# ZipArchive Framework 6 exception on temp filename

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I have strange thing with compressing file to temp file. When generating temp filename and compress I getting exception but when I set static filename there is no problems and exceptions. What is wrong?

```
tmp0 = Path.GetTempFileName();
WriteSomeDataToFileAndClose(tmp0);

tmp1 = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var fileStream = new FileStream(tmp1, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (ZipArchive zip2 = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        zip2.CreateEntryFromFile(tmp0, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tmp0), CompressionLevel.Fastest);
    }
}
```

Error:

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: The invocation of the constructor on type

Comment: Feels like some of that error message is missing. And also that the error you're getting is actually unrelated to the code you're showing.

Comment: At a guess: are you sure the file is being closed? And why do you need to write it to a temporary file, why not keep it in memory?

Comment: Thank You for help. It's strange. GetTempFileName creates file and ZipArchive problem with already exists ;) FileMode.OpenOrCreate